# How to get user's Cover on Facebook via javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use several types of url:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=cover', function(response) {
FB.api('/{userid}?fields=cover', function(response) {
FB.api('/{userid}/fields=cover', function(response) {
```

but also get facebook id only.
I can get user profile pic when the code:

```
FB.api("/me/picture?width=180&height=180"
```

how to get user's cover?
thanks

Comment: `me?fields=cover` is working for me in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: @JasonSperske https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dcover it is not working

Answer (score 1):

When you query a cover picture, additional information is returned with the object. You have to traverse through the object and get the value of `source`.

```
  FB.api('/me?fields=cover', function(response) {
        console.log(response.cover.source);
  });
```

Always use `console.log(object);` to see what it has got in it.

Comment: dose it need to apply something? and need to facebook accept then the api can get the cover info?